# Sage usage to calculate a cardinality

Tags: elliptic-curves, sagemath

I would like to compute the cardinality of an elliptic curve group over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{991}$. I'm trying to use sage but I still have an error in the syntax (I never used it before and I tryed to adapt a code). Here is what I have:

sage: E = EllipticCurve(GF(991))

sage: E

Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 446*x + 471 over Finite Field of order 991

Does some one know how I should modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the wrong place to ask and in future, you should ask on ask.sagemath.org.

To answer your question, you can find the cardinality by typing

```
sage: E.cardinality()
```

But, you need to first input your curve, say you have an elliptic curve given by
$$E: y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6 \text{ over } GF(p)$$

Then, do this,

```
sage: E=EllipticCurve(GF(p),[a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6])
sage: E.cardinality()
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: To be far, ask.sagemath.org is only available to those with a certain rep there currently, due to spammers... but I would suggest stackoverflow.com as a more appropriate venue, yes.  Is it possible to migrate a question there?

Comment: @kcrisman ask.sagemath.org works the same way as math.se, so I don't see why OP can't ask this question there. You only need to register and you should be able to ask a question with just $1$ rep, just like the way it is here.

Comment: Unfortunately, we had to close off the 1 rep threshold due to very aggressive spammers.  I think it's now 10, though the plan is to go back soon.

Comment: @kcrisman That's a pity, and I didn't know that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I think this forum is a fine place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [MAGMA online](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). I usually do it like this:

> K:=GF(991);
>
> g:=Generator(K);
>
> E:=EllipticCurve([0,0,0,446*g,471*g]);
>
> #E;

and MAGMA returns 984.